# Inline CSS Centering Not Working

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm using [this awesome site](http://howtocenterincss.com/) as a guide to inline CSS centering and am confused why most of it isn't working. The newer `flexbox` style only centers horizontally, not vertically:

```html
<div style="display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center;">
  <img src="https://66.media.tumblr.com/bac96f9db0dd31f09bad7f05db7e13c4/tumblr_o74utbKePP1u5sqevo1_500.gif"></img>
</div>
```

Whereas the legacy version for IE isn't working at all:

```html
<div style="display:table;">
  <div style="display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle;">
    <div style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">
      <img src="https://66.media.tumblr.com/bac96f9db0dd31f09bad7f05db7e13c4/tumblr_o74utbKePP1u5sqevo1_500.gif"></img>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas what the issue is? FYI, example image contains Orphan Black spoilers :)

Comment: So you want the image fully centered on your screen. Horizontally and vertically?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zYx4g/331/ Take a look at this

Comment: FYI, `<img src="..."></img>` isn't valid: `<img>` shouldn't be closed: `<img src="...">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- with `flexbox` you need to set `height`

#### NOTE

`<img>` is a self-closing tag so you don't need to do `</img>` but instead `/>`

---

```css
body {
  margin: 0
}
div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://66.media.tumblr.com/bac96f9db0dd31f09bad7f05db7e13c4/tumblr_o74utbKePP1u5sqevo1_500.gif" />
</div>
```

- regarding to `CSS tables` you need to set `height`  in order to `vertical-align:middle` work, and add `display:block`, `margin:auto` to `img` to get it centered horizontally

```css
body {
  margin: 0
}
div:first-of-type {
  display: table;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh
}
div:last-of-type {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle
}
img {
  display: block;
  margin: auto
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://66.media.tumblr.com/bac96f9db0dd31f09bad7f05db7e13c4/tumblr_o74utbKePP1u5sqevo1_500.gif" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! So much for that site I described as "awesome." It explicitly says you don't have to specify the size, although in this case I'm just using 100% for each (figured % is better than vh since I'd rather have it centered in the window than viewport). But any idea how to do this in anything below IE10? Someone said I need to set position to relative for both the img and the divs, but it makes no difference for me.

Comment: I've just updated my answer with regards to your second example ( I took awhile because I was caught up with work), and I just used `vh` for the sake of easiness to demo.

Comment: @Sophia take a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19026884/flexbox-center-horizontally-and-vertically/19027949#19027949), it might help you understand a few things

Comment: Sorry to keep with the questions, but is there a way to make this second method work with `position: absolute`? I'm using a framework to render canvas elements that need to sit directly on top of each other for compositing with alpha channels so if I use relative positioning that obviously doesn't work.

Comment: I'm pretty that's doable but I would need to see the code to help you better

Comment: It's too complicated to paste here, but something like [this](http://sretaeper.ucoz.com/stalker_Ractive/) except with the canvases positioned on top of one another. It's really no different than the example I used here. I just need absolute positioning and unless I'm missing something none of the techniques shown here work with that.

Comment: Except flexbox, of course. That's _so_ much better if I don't care about 1:200 users.

Comment: Now that I'm playing around with it more, it's not about the framework at all. I get the same issues using absolute positioning with your flexbox demo :/

Comment: @sophia im not at the computer now but I'll see that ASAP.

Comment: No worries! Can't complain about free help :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112088/discussion-between-dippas-and-sophia).

Answer (score 0):

It's working man. All you have to do is to specify the height of the parent div. Say for the 100% viewport height , you have to set it to 100vh.

**Code Example**

```
<div style="display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center;height: 100vh;
">
```

Answer (score 0):

The `div` containing the image sizes itself to the image height so vertical centering is irrelevant. Give that `div` an explicit height larger than the image height and the Flexbox version will work fine. Not sure about the fallback.

Like so:
`<div style="display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center;height:800px;">`

See here: http://codepen.io/SteveClason/pen/GZaoZZ